Is it possible to access a shared mailbox from my personal using python win32com?
I am creating a python script to automate a task for me. The task requires me to access a shared outlook mailbox and save an attachment. Although its accessible from my account in the browser version of Outlook, I am having trouble finding it using win32com.
This is how I'm currently accessing outlook.
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application').GetNamespace("MAPI")
    mailbox = outlook.Folders("myaccount@email.com")
    inbox = mailbox.Folders(2)


    # FOR TESTING
    for folder in outlook.Folders:
        print(folder.Name)
        for folderr in folder.Folders:
            print("\t" + folderr.Name)
            for folderrr in folderr.Folders:
                print("\t \t" + folderrr.Name)

I created the nested loops to try to find the shared mailbox somewhere and it is nowhere to be found. Is there some way to access it without having to sign into the shared mailbox? Simply typing the shared mailbox email such as this:
mailbox=outlook.Folders("shared@email.com")

does not work. I also do not have the credentials to log in to the shared mailbox directly.
